# Newbie to Javascript. Can someone tells me if this is the right way to write?

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm begging for someone to show me how this task should be done and where I went wrong. so the code I wrote was the best as I could get towards the answer and by some tutorials I was instructed to read. Not sure if it is right or with it is just crap. I'm completely new to this and this challenge my give some spot to learn it for real. Any help would be appreciated. Here is as far as I got:

Comment: In your `createStatue` method, you're already pushing the statue into the array so, don't need to call `statues.push` again

Comment: Also, in the `getAverageHeight`, you **don't** need `average_height`. You can just return `(total_heightInMeters / statues.length).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall I would say good job on what you have done. Dunno what happened to the indentation towards the end but i'll let you off.

to start with, in your object declaration you need to pass in height in meters rather than "Number".

Secondly since your CreateStatues method returns a statue object, and then you are pushing it to your array, it is unnecessary to push the statue to the array within the method (Which you do directly after creating the object)

other than that I think it is mostly fine although i haven't tested it but at a glance it seems fine.

finally make sure to format it properly, meaning 2 or 4 spaces indentation after each curly bracket.